# CSV Config Element Sharing Mode

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I've a scenario in which there are two thread groups. Lets say both thread groups (Thread A & Thread B) contains the procedure for subscription by two different ways. Now the thing is The CSV values used by Thread A can not be used to to subscribe through Thread B (because the subscription will already be done by thread A).

So, I want to ask how to set CSV Data Set Element's Sharing Mode such that both Threads take totally separate values (Thread A doesn't use a CSV value used by Thread B and vice versa) from the same CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Default Sharing Mode of `All Threads` fits your need, this way each thread (virtual user) reads next line at each iteration:

[image]

CSV Data Set Config setup just in case:

[image]

and the CSV file:

[image]

just make sure to place the CSV Data Set Config at the same level as Thread Groups, this way it will work as in the above screenshots.

More information:

- [CSV Data Set Config in Sharing Mode - Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy)
- [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)